# print the HTML files using a bluetooth printer issue

Tags: java, android

I have used the code for printing as given below

```
btn_print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket
                                .getOutputStream();
                        String BILL ="\n"+ oEditText.getText().toString();


                        os.write(BILL.getBytes());

                        Spanned ni = Html.fromHtml("<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body</html>");
                        System.out.println("*******ni****"+ni);

                        os.write(ni.toString().getBytes());


                        // This is printer specific code you can comment
                        // ==== > Start

                        // Setting height
                        int gs = 29;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(gs));
                        int h = 104;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(h));
                        int n = 162;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(n));

                        // Setting Width
                        int gs_width = 29;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(gs_width));
                        int w = 119;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(w));
                        int n_width = 2;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(n_width));

                        // Print BarCode
                        int gs1 = 29;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(gs1));
                        int k = 107;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(k));
                        int m = 73;
                        os.write(intToByteArray(m));

                        String barCodeVal = "ASDFC028060000005";// "HELLO12345678912345012";
                        System.out.println("Barcode Length : "
                                + barCodeVal.length());
                        int n1 = barCodeVal.length();
                        os.write(intToByteArray(n1));

                        for (int i = 0; i < barCodeVal.length(); i++) {
                            os.write((barCodeVal.charAt(i) + "").getBytes());
                        }
                        // printer specific code you can comment ==== > End
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Main", "Exe ", e);
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
```

and the i got the output as

> You Scored 192 points

the correct output i want is

> You Scored **192** points

That is 192 should be bold.Any one help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Please modify this line:

```
Spanned ni = Html.fromHtml("<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body</html>");
```

to

```
Spanned ni = Html.fromHtml("You scored <b>192</b> points.");
```

I wonder why are you providing `<html>`, `<body>` tags inside `Html.fromHtml`

Comment: but i can't covert the spanned to byte arry.Then only i can print